# register DNS for connecting to my computer

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns, remote-access

I am using a PC at university and I need to set up a DNS name for it under the network of university such as:

```
my-pc.dm.myuniversity.edu
```

for accessing this computer via my laptop from home (through remote connection).

Though, there are a lot of questions about setting up DNS with specific IPs, I can't find any method for setting a DNS for connecting to the current computer.

**Update**

My question is just about setting a DNS for the network to connect this computer via name rather than IP. Windows has such option in a very convenient way. And IT technicians as usual never assist with Linux users.

**Update**

My laptop at home has windows on it and my pc at university has Ubuntu Linux. At home i connect to university VPN and then I use team-viewer. Instead of using team-viewer ID, I want to use DNS name.

Comment: To see what your computer thinks, try `getent hosts` and add your computers name. But how is your MS Windows getting to set the name? Shore it isn't registered by the it department?

Answer (score 0):

You PC should already have a name. You can find out which one that is by executing command:

```
hostname
```

The ip address tied to that name is found via:

```
nslookup `hostname`
```

or alternatively:

```
ifconfig
```

But now back to your original question ;-)

You will only be able to access your computer at university remotely, if the university has set up remote access for their local network. You will have to talk to the IT department to find out how to access your computer remotely and what VNC or RDP software you have to install.

This can be set up in different ways, so there is no standard answer.

Comment: I already know the PC name just by opening a terminal and see `user@pcname`. However, my question is just about setting a DNS for the network to connect via name rather than IP. Windows has such option in a very convenient way. And IT technicians as usual never assist with linux.

Comment: If you want your computer name to be known by the DNS server of your local network, someone will have to add it to it. If your are lucky then the DHCP services is set up properly i.e. it will recognise your computer name. You can find out by executing command nslookup  'hostname' (must be reverse ticks).

Comment: I totally disagree. At least in windows I could register my favorite DNS name under university domain.

Comment: That is correct - That is because it is Windows.  When you power up your Windows box, it will start talking to the DHCP server (or the Windows equivalent) that will give your Windows box an ip address and your Windows box will give it your computer name in return. The same is possible in Ubuntu. It might already work like that out of the box. The way to check that is to do an nslookup of your computername.

Answer (score 0):

well for this you need to do is port forwarding. If you want to access all files of computer than you need to forward port 22 which is for ssh connection and you also need to install ssh-server to that computer using

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

after installing you need to access router of your university where Internet connection is coming and than you need to port forward 22 with static ip address of your University local pc.

after that you can access your University pc from anywhere. But know this that it will be open to access to anyone so take necessary steps for security of your university system.

to get remote access you can take ssh connection like this

```
ssh pc-username@domailname
```

Comment: sorry, my laptop at home has windows on it and my pc at uni has ubuntu linux. At home i connect to university VPN and then I use team-viewer. Instead of using team-viewer ID, I want to use DNS name.